# KeyError: 0 Python

Tags: python, keyerror

Hi I'm still pretty new in python and would like to know why this line:

```
    RP[p][t] = demand[p][t] / fillingrate[p]
```

is leading to the error: KeyError: 0

it follows the relevant part of the code. Is it just a mistake of notation or what's the best way to solve it?

```
productname = ('milk', 'yoghurt', 'buttermilk')
fillingrate = (1.5, 1.0, 2.0)

day = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14)

demand = [
(5, 4, 3, 3, 4, 9, 13, 5, 4, 4, 3, 5, 10, 12),
(3, 5, 3, 5, 5, 4,  3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4,  5,  5),
(3, 3, 5, 4, 4, 5,  4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5,  4,  5)
]

T = range (len(day))
P = range (len(productname))


for p in P:
   for t in T:
        RP[P,T] = model.addVar (lb = 0, vtype = GRB.CONTINUOUS,
        name = 'Regular Production[' + str(p) + ',' + str(t) + ']')
        print(demand[p][t])
        print(fillingrate[p])
        RP[p][t] = demand[p][t] / fillingrate[p]
        print(RP[p][t])
```

Comment: You are indexing `RP` with `[P,T]`, which is a tuple of ranges.  Where is `RP` declared?  Where does `RP` get a `[0]` element?

Answer (score 6):

Indexing by `[x, y]` is *absolutely not the same* as indexing by `[x][y]`. The former results in a single dimension indexed using a tuple, whereas the latter results in a ragged 2-D array.

You will need to create a new object at the index `[x]` containing the values you want.

Answer (score 1):

The expression `P` is not the same as `p`. In your code, the first is a range, the second is an integer from that range.

So, the expression `RP[P,T]` is wrong in two ways: it uses the wrong subscripts, and combines them the wrong way (as another answer points out).

I think you want `RP[p][t]` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`keyerror: 0` generally means that you are trying to access the value stored in a non-existing key `0` in a dictionary.

In your code it happens because, being

```
day = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14)
T = range (len(day))
```

you get

```
print(T)
```

> ```
> range(0, 14)
> ```

so its first element is `0`,
and when you run this

```
for p in P:
   for t in T:
        RP[P,T] = model.addVar (lb = 0, vtype = GRB.CONTINUOUS,
        name = 'Regular Production[' + str(p) + ',' + str(t) + ']')
        print(demand[p][t])
        print(fillingrate[p]) 
        RP[p][t] = demand[p][t] / fillingrate[p] 
        print(RP[p][t])
```

you have that the first value got by `t` is `0`, and then at line

```
RP[p][t] = demand[p][t] / fillingrate[p]
```

when you pass that `t` to dictionary `RP` (which I guess has no key `0`) a `keyerror: 0` is raised.

Also, as pointed out by other questions, you should notice that

> Indexing by [x, y] is *absolutely not the same* as indexing by [x][y].
> The former results in a single dimension indexed using a tuple,
> whereas the latter results in a ragged 2-D array.

To help you fix your code it might be useful to know how `RP` is defined.

Comment: ``demand`` is a *list*, which definitely has an *index* ``0``; it won't fail a lookup of ``0`` and it will never raise a ``KeyError``. The question is about an error two lines later.

Comment: thanks, actually I pick up the wrong variable as I was writing the answer. I updated the answer.